# How can I specify a CC0 1.0 license with doclicense?

Tags: hyperref, metadata, hyperxmp, doclicense

I'm loading `doclicense` as follows

```latex
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={0},
    version={1.0}
]{doclicense}
```

I am not sure 0 is a good modifier. Anyway, on Overleaf I get an "Error: License long name not defined". It goes on to say:

```
See the doclicense package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.398 \doclicense@set
                     %
Please check the manual of doclicense to see what you can do about it.
```

Unfortunately the manual isn't very useful as there is no example to set up a CC0 license nor does it say not to set a long name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit of digging, but looking at the support files you need `zero` no `0`:

```latex
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={zero},
    version={1.0}
]{doclicense}
```

Comment: I think this could do be clarified in the docs for `doclicense` ;)

Comment: Indeed, thank you! :)